# Given two overlapping datasets (think Venn Diagram), what is the point/plane called that separates the middle from either side?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, graphing-functions, machine-learning

[image: Terminology]

Or, if you prefer a typed out version:

Given the following two datasets:

```
[Category A]: 1,3,4,7,8,9,13 ... 28,30
[Category B]: 29,32,33,37 ... 61,62,63
```

Plotted like so:

```
 A-AA--AAA---AA--A--A-AAA-B-ABA-BB-A-B-B-B-BB-B--BBB-B--BBBB-BBB
0---------10--------20--------30--------40--------50--------60--------70--------80--------90--------100
```

One might say the `Vector` is the point (or plane or boundary) in between the most `A`s and `B`s. Or rather, the statistical point that separates the two datasets (`A` and `B`). Like so:

```
A-AA--AAA---AA--A--A-AAA-B-ABA-BB-A-B-B-B-BB-B--BBB-B--BBBB-BBB
                              ^-- Vector (or "optimum hyperplane", or boundary)
```

But what is the point called where there are no more `A`s greater than called?  Or at least the point where it's statistically "unlikely" (in soft terms) that any point above this number include a point belonging to the `A` category.

---

```
 A-AA--AAA---AA--A--A-AAA-B-ABA-BB-A-B-B-B-BB-B--BBB-B--BBBB-BBB
|--Probably A-----------|---????---|--Probably B----------------|
  What's this called? --^     ^    ^-- What's this called?
                              ^-- Vector (or "plane", or "boundary")
```

---

In other words:

```
 A-AA--AAA---AA--A--A-AAA-B-ABA-BB-A-B-B-B-BB-B--BBB-B--BBBB-BBB
|--Probably A---------|-Questionable-|--Probably B--------------|
<-- More likely A ------Maybe A or B----------- More likely B -->
```

Therefore if given an un-labeled or uncategorized points 1, 2, and 3:

```
 ---------1?------------------2?------------3?------------------
|--Probably A---------|-Questionable-|--Probably B--------------|
<-- More likely A ------Maybe A or B----------- More likely B -->
```

From this we can share that 1 is likely A, 2 is unknown since it's so close to the vector (maybe a probability of 50%), and 3 is B.

I know the term for the point in the middle (vector).  But what are the terms for the other points that separate the questionable area from the clear area?

If the `vector` is the point between the most `A`s and `B`s, what is the point where there are no more `A`s called?

Comment: What do you mean by the most Xs and Ys above and below? Is "above" to the left or to the right? And what is this data, exactly? Just a string of the characters 'X', 'Y', and '-'?

Comment: I just edited the question. Is this clearer? Yes, I conflated "above" and "below" with "greater" and "lesser". The data is just two categories of data.

Comment: Just made a ton of edits to be clearer. Please remove hold, or advise on how to further clarify this question.

Comment: Would this be called a "Support Vector"? As in: http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~yuhuang/samsung/SVM.jpg

Comment: Or maybe "margin"?

Comment: Voted to reopen. I have no idea what it might be called, but at least I understand what you're asking now.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Any tips on how to make it more clear to get more votes to reopen?

Comment: Just noticed that using X and Y may not have been the best choice in category labels. Switched to A, B to avoid confusion with literal X,Y axes.

Answer (score 1):

In convex analysis, there is a [separating hyperplane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) between two disjoint convex bodies. However, it looks like you are trying to do classification. There are techniques in classification that use a similar notion to attempt to separate two or more datasets. These are called *maximum margin hyperplanes*. See [Support Vector Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine).

EDIT: You are also asking about points that lie in the margin (the supposed gap between the sets). When the data sets cannot be cleanly separated, it is typically referred to as a *soft margin*. This is also mentioned in the Wikipedia article I linked to.